# login_decorator not working for ajax

Tags: decorator, django-authentication, python-decorators

I am using Ajax in my template. It calls a view (ajax_view()). I have applied login decorator on this view so that if user is not logged in then he should first be directed to login page.

But it is not working. Login decorators work on every view except for views that use Ajax.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

On ajax calls also the http response is actually a redirect to the login page, but your page will not redirect as this is an asynchronous call. 
You probably want to do something like this:

```
def ajax_login_required(f):
 def wrap(request, *args):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
   return f(request, *args)
  else:
   if request.is_ajax():
     return HttpResponse('false')
   else:
     return login_required(f)(request, *args)
 return wrap

@ajax_login_required
def ajax_view(request):
 #------some code here---------
```

Now after this, you gotta do a minor change in your javascript.
This might change according to your ajax call.

```
$.getJSON("/my_ajax_url",{},function(r){
  if(!r){window.location='/accounts/login'}
})
```